# Power BI: Categorize customers based on measures

Tags: powerbi

I have a list of customers that I wish to categorize based on two criteria: Share of total income and average time from due date to payment date.

I have a table with customer transactions that I can use to calculate these two criteria.

The solution I currently have is to use calculated columns in the customer table:

Sum of invoiced amount per customer/Total sum all customers = Share of total income

Average number of days per customer

I then use IF-functions to categorize these metrics into Big/Medium/Small customers, and Good/Medium/Bad payers.

Next I use a Matrix visualization to see number of customers for each category (Big customer/Good payer, Small Customer/Medium payer, and so on).

The problem I get is that the outcome of this is static, and they doesn't change if I use slicers to get only transactions from one year, or for only one of our companies.

Can I instead use measures for this, and get a dynamic Matrix visualization?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use measures for this. It is a common pattern known as dynamic segmentation. You can read how to implement it here: https://www.daxpatterns.com/dynamic-segmentation/